# Render Opportunity name from LookUp Relationship

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, lookup

I have a Custom Object that has a reference to Opportunities, I originally had it set up with a Master-Detail relationship but then after reading [this](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1api/Content/pages_quick_start_display_field_values.htm) and noting that parent objects can't be referenced, as well as the Master-Detail relationship only storing the ID, I switched the field type to a LookUp one.

So now my object's custom field's datatype is:  `Lookup(Opportunity)` and I'm trying to make a VisualForce page that uses the StandardController (with reference to my custom object) render the *name* of the Opportunity. But the relationship doesn't seem to work and I just get `unknown property String.name` when I try. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here's a bit of sample code:

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObj__c" recordSetVar="objs">
    <apex:pageBlock title="">
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! objs}" var="item" >
            <apex:column headerValue="Opp. Name">
                <apex:outputText value="{! item.opp_to_exp__c.Name}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Opportunity">
                <apex:outputText value="{! item.opp_to_exp__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

So `opp_to_exp__c` is API name for the field, and I've ripped out the specifics of the names and such besides that API name. I have no trouble rendering the other fields up of the object, just this lookUp one it seems.

The error message suggests to me that the `opp_to_exp__c` is still just a String for some reason even though I've changed the data type to be a LookUp one.

Can anyone help? I've spent over a few hours reading documentation and trying to find the right KeyTerms to search for on here with no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try replacing __c with __r i.e.

```
item.opp_to_exp__r.Name
```

That's typically how you reference related objects

Comment: Oh jeez. Nope, but that just worked. I must have managed to stare right past it in the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing some stuff. What do you mean by "parent objects can't be referenced"? Or by "Master-Detail relationship only storing the ID" (because so does the lookup relationship; let's say M-D has different benefits/considerations but in both cases only the Id - like a foreign key - is stored on the object that has the lookup field).

To quick & dirty fix your Visualforce - use `<apex:outputText value="{! item.opp_to_exp__r.Name}"/>`.

To read a bit why - check http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm and http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_custom_objects.htm

Comment: I accidently linked to the wrong thing in my question, I was referring to this: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_quick_start_tabs.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fpages_quick_start_tabs.htm|SkinName=webhelp where it says: "You cannot access parent objects using this expression language. In other words, {!account.parent.name} will return an error." which was confusing to me

Comment: Hm, wrong link again? :) http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1api/Content/pages_quick_start_display_field_values.htm I assume. I think it's incorrect, this works just fine for me: `<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:outputText value="{!account.parent.name}" />
</apex:page>` (need to access it as `/apex/pageName?id=someAccountsId`, preferably with Id of an account that has a parent but not necessarily. You can even go `{!account.parent.owner.profile.name}` if you want.

Comment: Gah, I don't know why it keeps using the wrong link, I swear I put in the right one! But yes the one you linked to there is the I was referring to. Thanks.

Comment: Docs use iframes, very annoying indeed. I either right click & open frame in new tab (FF) or click the top "email me this" icon and copy from there...